# Download method of type void vs response

Tags: design, design-patterns, python, naming, backward-compatibility

Given a method that is widely used and has a void return type:

```
from somepackage import download_model
from somepackage import get_filename

def download(name, download_path):
   response = download_model(name, download_path)
   file_name = response.filename
   file_path = model_download_folder + file_name
   if file_name.endswith(".tar.gz"):
       with tarfile.open(file_path, "r:gz") as tar_file:
           tar_file.extractall(path=download_path)
```

This method downloads a folder or a tar file. Then, if the downloaded file is a tar, it extracts it, and the suffix had the file name. For example, if download is called with `download_path=/some/path/` and `response.filename` is 'model.tar.gz' the actual content of the tar will be in `/some/path/model/`.

This method is currently hiding the `filename` in the `response`. So far, the filename was hard-coded and fixed for all downloads. Recently new models was added and now the filename might be anything. The caller to `download` in this case, should be able to get the path where the files were extracted (e.g. `/some/path/model/`).

Alternatives:

1. Change `download` to return the `response`/`filename`
2. Store the response in a global field and then add another method to get it
3. Call to `get_filename` (which wasn't used so far) to get the `filename`

Assume that backwards compatibility is a constraint. Which one of these options would you recommend and why.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what it's doing now.  So the method currently has no 'return' statement?  What does it actually do?

Comment: why can't you just return the filename?

Comment: "there is a new requirement and the filename needs to be accessible after calling download" - that's not exactly a full description of a requirement; it's not a "why" (a reason behind the requirement), but more a "how" (it's a partial description in terms of how you'd go about implementing it). In other words, the requirement is likely something along the lines of: "if the dwnld was successful, something needs to happen (and the filename is needed for *that*)". So I suppose you should return the response to client code, which should check if it's valid (or something like that).

Comment: Regarding your other options: 
(2.) is an unstructured, ad hoc access to a global, which is just a terribly bad practice. 
(3.) get_filename doesn't allow you to check if the download was successful (or whatever `response` allows for), and given that the filename is already extracted in `response.filename`, isn't DRY. Also, it doesn't conceptually correspond to what the code is doing at this level (it's not trying to extract a filename from some path, but to do something related to this particular download).

Comment: Is this a specific technical question that would be better on StackOverflow? or is this more of a philosophical question of what works best?

Comment: @FilipMilovanović - I've added more details what I'm trying to accomplish here. Also, I agree with your mentioned considerations (consider posting it as an answer). I actually have a preference here, but I'm trying to present the problem in unbiased manner.

Comment: @JimmyJames - yes it currently doesn't have a return statement. It downloads a file or folder and opens the tar if needed. I've edited the question.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović - any cons for the first option?

Comment: All functions/methods in Python have an implicit return value of `None` when there is nothing returned.  Changing this to return the filename would only break something if some caller were depending on the method always returning `None`.  While possible, it seems highly unlikely that would be the case.  Callers who ignore the return value will be unaware of the change.

Comment: @JimmyJames - thanks. The reason for this question is a major pushback to option #1. no one relies on the return type so this is ok.

Comment: What was the reason given for that pushback?

Comment: "returning a model or a file name from a function that is supposed to be void as per name definition (download) is not acceptable."

Comment: "any cons for the first option?" - I don't know enough about your particular circumstances, but now that you've said that a major element of the pushback is  that the function was "supposed to be void as per name definition (download)", I'll say this - you can change what a function was supposed to be (you can reconceptualize it), especially if the impact of doing so will be limited (there's no cascading reliance in the call chain on the fact that it was void). 1/2

Comment: The pushback rests on the premise that the original conception was perfect (that the original design is the right design), even though you didn't have all information that was relevant at the time (you only now learned that the filename can be anything). Nobody's fault, this is perfectly normal. Given the new state of affairs, there's little sense to hold on to every aspect of the original conception. If the impact is limited, it's perfectly fine to change some conceptual aspect of a function. If it isn't called in too many places, you can even change the name to reflect that 2/2.

Comment: My thought was, that option #2 and #3 creates more problems than it solves. #2 adds the need to handle concurrency. #3 adds another method call to get information that existed in the first call, sounds confusing and redundant.

Comment: @YosiDahari So the issue is an internal naming standard?  There's nothing really changing about 'the signature' here.  If was something like how you used to return a filename and changed it to return a generator e.g. made it async, that would be something entirely different.  Even in languages that do support void (e.g. Java) adding a return value is completely risk free refactoring.